# Component in next.js Cannot be user as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jsx

I have trouble with making my mobile menu working. I wanted to make it above the other content using use effect, but I failed and now whole project is not working. That's the error I get. I tried to fix it, but I can't. Please help and forgive my studpidity.

[image]

```
/* @jsxImportSource next/client */

import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Menu, Transition, Disclosure } from "@headlessui/react";
import Container from "@/components/container";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import { urlForImage } from "@/lib/sanity/image";
import cx from "clsx";
import { ChevronDownIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";
import { useTransition, animated } from 'react-spring'

export default function Navbar(props) {
  const leftmenu = [
    {
      label: "Home",
      href: "/"
    },
    {
      label: "About",
      href: "/about"
    },
    {
      label: "Contact",
      href: "/contact"
    },
    {
      label: "Archive",
      href: "/archive"
    },
  ];

  const MobileMenu = () => {
    const [isMobileMenuOpen, setIsMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleMobileMenuToggle = () => {
      setIsMobileMenuOpen(!isMobileMenuOpen);
    };

    const handleMobileMenuLinkClick = () => {
      setIsMobileMenuOpen(false);
    };

    const mobilemenu = [...leftmenu];

    return (
      <Container>
        {isMobileMenuOpen && (
          <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50 z-50" onClick={handleMobileMenuToggle} />
        )}
        <nav>
          <Disclosure>
            {({ open }) => (
              <>
                <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-between md:flex-nowrap md:gap-10 h-24 border-b-2 border-gray-100">
                  <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-between">
                    <Link href="/" className="w-48 dark:hidden">
                      {props.logo ? (
                        <Image 
                          {...urlForImage(props.logo)}
                          alt="Logo"
                          priority={true}
                          sizes="(max-width: 1040px) 100vw, 400px"
                        />
                      ) : (
                        <span className="block text-center">
                          Ideato
                        </span>
                      )}
                    </Link>
                    <Link href="/" className="hidden w-48 dark:block">
                      {props.logoalt ? (
                        <Image
                          {...urlForImage(props.logoalt)}
                          alt="Logo"
                          priority={true}
                          sizes="(max-width: 1040px) 100vw, 400px"
                        />
                      ) : (
                        <span className="block text-center">
                          Ideato
                        </span>
                      )}
                    </Link>
                    <Disclosure.Button
                      aria-label="Toggle Menu"
                      className="ml-auto pt-4 h-full rounded-md px-2 py-1 text-gray-500 focus:text-blue-500 focus:outline-none dark:text-gray-300 md:hidden "  onClick={handleMobileMenuToggle} >
                      
                      <svg
                        className="h-8 w-8 fill-current"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        {open && (
                          <path
                            fillRule="evenodd"
                            clipRule="evenodd"
                            d="M18.278 16.864a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.414l-4.829-4.828-4.828 4.828a1 1 0 0 1-1.414-1.414l4.828-4.829-4.828-4.828a1 1 0 0 1 1.414-1.414l4.829 4.828 4.828-4.828a1 1 0 1 1 1.414 1.414l-4.828 4.829 4.828 4.828z"
                          />
                        )}
                        {!open && (
                          <path
                            fillRule="evenodd"
                            d="M4 5h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"
                          />
                        )}
                      </svg>
                    </Disclosure.Button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="order-1 hidden w-full flex-col items-center justify-start md:order-none md:flex md:w-auto md:flex-1 md:flex-row md:justify-end pt-4">
                    {leftmenu.map((item, index) => (
                      <Fragment key={`${item.label}${index}`}>
                        {item.children && item.children.length > 0 ? (
                          <DropdownMenu
                            menu={item}
                            key={`${item.label}${index}`}
                            items={item.children}
                          />
                        ) : (
                          <Link
                            href={item.href}
                            key={`${item.label}${index}`}
                            className="px-5 py-2 text-xl font-serif font-medium text-gray-600 hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-gray-400"
                            target={item.external ? "_blank" : ""}
                            rel={item.external ? "noopener" : ""}>
                            {item.label}
                          </Link>
                        )}
                      </Fragment>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <Disclosure.Panel>
                  <div className="text-xl font-serif hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-gray-40 order-2 -ml-4 mt-4 flex w-full flex-col items-center justify-start md:hidden">
                    {mobilemenu.map((item, index) => (
                      <Fragment key={`${item.label}${index}`}>
                        {item.children && item.children.length > 0 ? (
                          <DropdownMenu
                            menu={item}
                            key={`${item.label}${index}`}
                            items={item.children}
                            mobile={true}
                          />
                        ) : (
                          <Link
                            href={item.href}
                            key={`${item.label}${index}`}
                            className="w-full px-5 py-2 font-medium text-gray-600 hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-gray-400"
                            target={item.external ? "_blank" : ""}
                            rel={item.external ? "noopener" : ""}>
                            {item.label}
                          </Link>
                        )}
                      </Fragment>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </Disclosure.Panel>
              </>
            )}
          </Disclosure>
        </nav>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

I verified if the component is being imported properly in layout.tsx and it does. I need a solution.

Comment: why some of the files are .tsx and the rest are .js? I believe if you change the navbar file to .tsx and give it the type `ReactNode`, the error goes away. You have also one extra`{` at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared a React component, `MobileMenu`, inside the `Navbar` component, not used it, and then return nothing from the `Navbar` component which is invalid JSX.

Move the `MobileMenu` component outside `Navbar` and render it.

```
import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Menu, Transition, Disclosure } from "@headlessui/react";
import Container from "@/components/container";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import { urlForImage } from "@/lib/sanity/image";
import cx from "clsx";
import { ChevronDownIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";
import { useTransition, animated } from 'react-spring';

const leftmenu = [
  ....
];

const MobileMenu = (props) => {
  ....
};

export default function Navbar(props) {
  return <MobileMenu {...props} />;
}
```

Or since `Navbar` does nothing else, just directly return the JSX that `MobileMenu` would have rendered.

```
import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Menu, Transition, Disclosure } from "@headlessui/react";
import Container from "@/components/container";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import { urlForImage } from "@/lib/sanity/image";
import cx from "clsx";
import { ChevronDownIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";
import { useTransition, animated } from 'react-spring';

const leftmenu = [
  {
    label: "Home",
    href: "/"
  },
  {
    label: "About",
    href: "/about"
  },
  {
    label: "Contact",
    href: "/contact"
  },
  {
    label: "Archive",
    href: "/archive"
  },
];

export default function Navbar(props) {
  const [isMobileMenuOpen, setIsMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleMobileMenuToggle = () => {
    setIsMobileMenuOpen(!isMobileMenuOpen);
  };

  const handleMobileMenuLinkClick = () => {
    setIsMobileMenuOpen(false);
  };

  const mobilemenu = [...leftmenu];

  return (
    <Container>
      {isMobileMenuOpen && (
        <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50 z-50" onClick={handleMobileMenuToggle} />
      )}
      <nav>
        <Disclosure>
          {({ open }) => (
            <>
              <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-between md:flex-nowrap md:gap-10 h-24 border-b-2 border-gray-100">
              <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-between">
                <Link href="/" className="w-48 dark:hidden">
                  {props.logo ? (
                    <Image 
                      {...urlForImage(props.logo)}
                      alt="Logo"
                      priority={true}
                      sizes="(max-width: 1040px) 100vw, 400px"
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <span className="block text-center">
                      Ideato
                    </span>
                  )}
                </Link>
                <Link href="/" className="hidden w-48 dark:block">
                  {props.logoalt ? (
                    <Image
                      {...urlForImage(props.logoalt)}
                      alt="Logo"
                      priority={true}
                      sizes="(max-width: 1040px) 100vw, 400px"
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <span className="block text-center">
                      Ideato
                    </span>
                  )}
                </Link>
                <Disclosure.Button
                  aria-label="Toggle Menu"
                  className="ml-auto pt-4 h-full rounded-md px-2 py-1 text-gray-500 focus:text-blue-500 focus:outline-none dark:text-gray-300 md:hidden "  onClick={handleMobileMenuToggle} >
                  
                  <svg
                    className="h-8 w-8 fill-current"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    {open && (
                      <path
                        fillRule="evenodd"
                        clipRule="evenodd"
                        d="M18.278 16.864a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.414l-4.829-4.828-4.828 4.828a1 1 0 0 1-1.414-1.414l4.828-4.829-4.828-4.828a1 1 0 0 1 1.414-1.414l4.829 4.828 4.828-4.828a1 1 0 1 1 1.414 1.414l-4.828 4.829 4.828 4.828z"
                      />
                    )}
                    {!open && (
                      <path
                        fillRule="evenodd"
                        d="M4 5h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"
                      />
                    )}
                  </svg>
                </Disclosure.Button>
              </div>
              <div className="order-1 hidden w-full flex-col items-center justify-start md:order-none md:flex md:w-auto md:flex-1 md:flex-row md:justify-end pt-4">
                {leftmenu.map((item, index) => (
                  <Fragment key={`${item.label}${index}`}>
                    {item.children && item.children.length > 0 ? (
                      <DropdownMenu
                        menu={item}
                        key={`${item.label}${index}`}
                        items={item.children}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <Link
                        href={item.href}
                        key={`${item.label}${index}`}
                        className="px-5 py-2 text-xl font-serif font-medium text-gray-600 hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-gray-400"
                        target={item.external ? "_blank" : ""}
                        rel={item.external ? "noopener" : ""}>
                        {item.label}
                      </Link>
                    )}
                  </Fragment>
                ))}
                </div>
              </div>
              <Disclosure.Panel>
                <div className="text-xl font-serif hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-gray-40 order-2 -ml-4 mt-4 flex w-full flex-col items-center justify-start md:hidden">
                  {mobilemenu.map((item, index) => (
                    <Fragment key={`${item.label}${index}`}>
                      {item.children && item.children.length > 0 ? (
                        <DropdownMenu
                          menu={item}
                          key={`${item.label}${index}`}
                          items={item.children}
                          mobile={true}
                        />
                      ) : (
                        <Link
                          href={item.href}
                          key={`${item.label}${index}`}
                          className="w-full px-5 py-2 font-medium text-gray-600 hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-gray-400"
                          target={item.external ? "_blank" : ""}
                          rel={item.external ? "noopener" : ""}>
                          {item.label}
                        </Link>
                      )}
                    </Fragment>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </Disclosure.Panel>
            </>
          )}
        </Disclosure>
      </nav>
    </Container>
  );
}
```